# group_by and summarize_at in R language showing invalid 'type' (builtin) of argument

Tags: r

Given below are the details of my data.frame

```
Scrip <- rep(c("HAPPY"),times=10)
BuyOrSell <- rep(c("BUYING","SELLING"),each=5)
Qty <- rep(c(10,12,13,15,11,10,12,13,15,11))
NetAmt <- c(50,30,40,60,70,90,70,110,120,135)
dat <- data.frame(Scrip,BuyOrSell,Qty,NetAmt)
```

I am trying to consolidate on variables 'Scrip' and 'BuyOrSell" and Qty and NetAmt totalled with the following code using library(dplyr).

```
da1 <- dat %>% group_by(Scrip,BuyOrSell) %>% summarize_at(vars(Qty,NetAmt),list(Qty=sum))
```

It is reporting an error like "Error in list(Qty = sum) : invalid 'type' (builtin) of argument"
I am learning to use R. In my laptop, the above data in fact comes from a .csv file. The code was also working. But all of a sudden, it has started showing errors. I couldn't yet find a solution to it.

Comment: are you sure you want to use: "<=" maybe you want "<-" instead?

Comment: I am so sorry. Even with <- this also,the error continues to haunt me. @user12256545

Comment: your example works fine works wen i try it, so idk whats wrong

Comment: try   :   summarise_at(vars(Qty,NetAmt),sum)

Comment: Yes. You have solved my puzzling problem. Your reply works. fine.@user12256545

Comment: Up to yesterday i.e. 2021-03-11, there was no problem for the code to work on my laptop. The whole trouble started today. I spend long hours searching for an answer. I also checked if the data data types are similar or not. Because the complete comes from .csv file read into a data.frame. But nothing worked for me. until I tried the answer given above.Thank you to all. @user12256545